# How do i assign a number to each player in class player?

Tags: python, class

I have made this simple program all ut does so far is create tanks however i have come to a problem. I would like it to assign a number corrosponding to if its the first second third or fourth etc... could someone help me with this thanks in advance.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, tank_name):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_name = tank_name
        self.number = number


players = input('Please type player amount >>> ')

try:
    players = int(players)
except ValueError:
    print('Whoops... ' + players + ' is not a valid number. The auto amount is two players.')
    players = int(2)

number = 0


def new_player():
    name = input('What is your name >>> ')
    tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
    number = str(number)
    number = Player(name, tank_name)


for i in range(0, players):
    number = int(number)
    number = number + 1
    new_player()
    print()
    print('Next player or end of player creation.')
    print()
```

Comment: The code you are showing here has many basic issues. However, if you just need to assign a number to the tanks, you should add that parameter to the `Player` `__init__` method, and then us it inside the main `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `number` to `new_player` by changing it to this:

```
def new_player(number):
    name = input('What is your name >>> ')
    tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
    return Player(name, tank_name, number)
```

Note that I made it now `return` the created `Player` which you forgot to do.

We now give `number` to `Player`, so we need to change `__init__` to this:

```
def __init__(self, name, tank_name, number):
    self.name = name
    self.tank_name = tank_name
    self.number = number
```

Now you actually already have a variable called `number` that you increase by 1 each time (using `number = number + 1`), but you can instead use `i` directly like this. since the `range` will take care of increasing `i` by one each time for you:

```
for i in range(0, players):
    player = new_player(i)
    print()
    print('Next player or end of player creation.')
    print()
```

Note how I got rid of the `int` use, as `i` here is already an integer.

If you want to start the players at 1 instead of 0, you would change `new_player(i)` to `new_player(i + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend passing through a number variable to the class, and every time you are creating an instance of the Player class, you add one to the number. Also, it can be useful to store the instances of the class in list, and then you can access a specific player with the generator: [player for player in players if player.number == 1]

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, tank_name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_name = tank_name
        self.number = number

players = input('Please type player amount >>> ')

try:
    players = int(players)
except ValueError:
    print('Whoops... ' + players + ' is not a valid number. The auto amount is two players.')
    players = int(2)

number = 0
players = []
 
def new_player():
    name = input('What is your name >>> ')
    tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
    number += 1
    players.append(Player(name, tank_name, number))

for i in range(0, players):
    new_player()
    print()
    print('Next player or end of player creation.')
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also just add a class level counter so every new player gets a unique number.

```
class Player:
    playerctr = 0  # increment for each new player
    def __init__(self, name, tank_name):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_name = tank_name
        Player.playerctr += 1
        self.number = Player.playerctr # set current counter to this player
```